# How to get current loading progress in WebKit

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

I am using C# with .net 4.5.2 and WebKit 0.5 and I am stuck on how to make a progress bar that displays current page loading progress. Here is what I have and what I believe should work (from prior research):

```
this.webKitBrowser.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(Form1_ProgressChanged);
```

This is the line that is annoying me, apparently webkitBrowser.ProgressChanged doesn't exist. Is there a substitute available?

Thanks

EDIT:

I didn't post my whole snippet (I should have) but here is the rest of it:

```
private void Form1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
    }
```

Just a note of clarification, this.webKitBrowser.ProgressChanged is throwing an error, when I type it slowly into VS 2015 the drop down bar doesn't contain ProgressChanged. I concluded that ProgressChanged doesn't exist in WebKit but the EventHandler is there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the handler :

```
private void WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.CurrentProgress;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the main post. I already did that but the problem pertains to the code above. Thanks for your quick reply!